# ANT:exec command

Tags: ant

i have a set of Environment variables in ANT exec command as follows,

```
<exec dir="${basedir}/src/" command="/usr/local/covidien/HDE/x86.linux2.6/bin/idlpp -S -l java ${basedir}/src/HelloWorldData.idl" >         
                <env key="OSPL_HOME" value="/usr/local/covidien/HDE/x86.linux2.6"/>
                <env key="OSPL_TARGET" value="x86.linux2.6"/>
                <env key="PATH" value="$OSPL_HOME/bin:$PATH"/>
                <env key="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" value="$OSPL_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"/>
                <env key="CPATH" value="$OSPL_HOME/include:$OSPL_HOME/include/sys:$CPATH"/>
                <env key="OSPL_TMPL_PATH" value="$OSPL_HOME/etc/idlpp"/>
                <env key="OSPL_URI" value="$OSPL_HOME/etc/idlpp"/>
                <env key="CLASSPATH" value="$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpssaj.jar:$CLASSPATH"/>
                <env key="CLASSPATH" value="$OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpscj.jar:$CLASSPATH"/>
        </exec>
```

but it throws error as **error while loading shared libraries: libddsutil.so:**.I have an external lib which contains *.so files.I need to include it with exec command.How to add external lib with exec command

Answer (score 5):

Unix environment variables do not work within the ANT file, need to be imported as ANT properties. Also the arguments to the command must be specified separately. See the [exec task doco](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)

Try something like this:

```
<property environment="env"/>

<exec dir="${basedir}/src/" executable="/usr/local/covidien/HDE/x86.linux2.6/bin/idlpp">
        <arg line="-S -l java ${basedir}/src/HelloWorldData.idl" >         
        <env key="OSPL_HOME" value="/usr/local/covidien/HDE/x86.linux2.6"/>
        <env key="OSPL_TARGET" value="x86.linux2.6"/>
        <env key="PATH" value="${env.OSPL_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"/>
        <env key="LD_LIBRARY_PATH" value="${env.OSPL_HOME}/lib:${env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"/>
        <env key="CPATH" value="${env.OSPL_HOME}/include:${env.OSPL_HOME}/include/sys:${env.CPATH}"/>
        <env key="OSPL_TMPL_PATH" value="${env.OSPL_HOME}/etc/idlpp"/>
        <env key="OSPL_URI" value="${env.OSPL_HOME}/etc/idlpp"/>
        <env key="CLASSPATH" value="${env.OSPL_HOME}/jar/dcpssaj.jar:${env.CLASSPATH}"/>
</exec>
```